# How to make a string of all texts C#

Tags: c#, string, int, double, calculator

I am a beginner and I am doing a calculator with a console application in C#, I want to know how to make a string includes all the texts and words.
For example :
_ Enter the first number!
: stack
_ Error, cannot use texts in division!

So, I want to make a code like that

```
If (firstnumber == string) (not int or double){

Console.WriteLine("Error, cannot use texts in division");

}
```

Please, help me.

```
                                   Thanks
```

Comment: I think you need to explain better what are you trying to do. Do you want to check if the user doesn't type numbers?

Comment: Try to take a look at Int32.Parse or Int32.TryParse

Comment: Yes, bro     if the user doesn't type a number, the calculator will write "Error"

Answer (score 2):

I think is this you wont.

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();

try
{
    int firstNumber = int.Parse(input);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error, cannot use texts in division");
}
```

Comment: It looks like a `TryParse` is better for this case. But even with `Parse` approach catching all type of exceptions is not a best idea. How about to catch only `FormatException`?

Comment: You are right, but the question was marked as duplicate an i thing the best way is like @PilouPili post on link.